# JSP tag which is retrieved as String is not executed

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have Java class which is responsible for rendering some html elements and we have some predefined tags created for them.

```
public class StartDateField {

private static StartDateField object;

private StartDateField(){}

public static StartDateField getInstance(){

    if(object == null){
        object = new StartDateField();
    }
    return object;
}

public String render(){
    String field = "<field:text name='first_name' size='65' maxlen='63' style='field' />";
    return field;
}
```

}

Then I tried to call that render method inside the JSP tag (which also has import to above class)

```
<td colspan="2">
<%=StartDateField.getInstance(SUBpagebean).render()%>
</td>
```

But it displays nothing. When I go to view source it shows the returned text instead of executing the tag. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`<%= someExpression() %>` means: evaluate the Java expression `someExpression()`, and write its result to the HTTP response writer. So obviously, you're writing `<field:text name='first_name' size='65' maxlen='63' style='field' />` directly to the response.

A JSP tag must be in the static source code of the JSP to be evaluated.

Note that JSTL is a standard library of tags. `<field:text>` is a custom JSP tag. It's not a JSTL tag.

Comment: thanx JB for your nice explanation. Actually im working on how to generate some user defined fields. So as per you there is no way of sending the custom tags through the response and and render?

Comment: JSP tags are executed at server-side. They're not executed by the browser. Sending a JSP tag to the response doesn't make sense.

Comment: Great thanx...can't we initialize the custom tag by ourselves and call the relevant methods like this in JSP                                                             public void renderTag(){
  BeanFieldTag tag = new BeanFieldTag();
  tag.setName(this.subPageBean);
  tag.setProperty("sch_event_name");
  tag.setSize("30");
  tag.setMaxlen("100");
  tag.setStyle("field");
  
  tag.doEndTag();
 }

Comment: I fail to see the point. If you want to call the methods of the tag yourself rather than letting the container do it, just use regular objects.